# How to generate a report using SOAtest

Tags: parasoft

I am generating a SOAtest report after running the parasoft SOAtest from command line,  I am seeing results at Test case level where for one test there are multiple validations from Datasource. How can I generate that gives me report on all validation I am doing rather than just the Tests in suite

Answer (score 0):

(SOATest 9.8)Below gives you Complete Validation report in test suite hierarchy structure in  HTML or XML.

Right click on .tst Structure report, Select your configuration and file format you need the report in.

Comment: The report I am getting talks only about tasks and Tests. As you know , one test in Parasoft deals with multiple assertions. Can I get a report based on assertions and numbder of times assertion is run based on datasource

Comment: So, Just after running the SOATests, You can see Generate Report on Bottom right(Default perspective). also Report & Publish does the same Job.