# How to generate a XML report using Parasoft SOAtest 9.9.x

Tags: visual-studio, parasoft

I want to generate a XML reporting SOAtest as indicated by **https://github.com/parasoft/SOAtestToMTM** but I don't have the same result. I followed exactly the same steps but my 'TAGS' are completely different.

I use the Parasoft SOAtest version 9.9.5.

**The XML result as indicated by SOAtestToMTM solution is like that:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<ResultsSession buildId="build-2016-08-18 15:17:02" date="08/18/16 15:17:02" project="Default Project" tag="Example Configuration" time="2016-08-18T15:17:02-07:00" toolName="SOAtest" toolVer="9.9.3.20151123">
    <TestConfig machine="nitrogen" name="Example Configuration" pseudoUrl="soatest.user://Example Configuration" user="kchen" />
    <Authors>
        <Author id="dev1" name="kchen" />
    </Authors>
    <VersionInfos>
        <StorageInfo ownerId="com.parasoft.xtest.checkers.api.execution" resultId="IFunctionalTestViolation" ver="3" />
...
        <StorageInfo ownerId="com.parasoft.xtest.checkers.api.standards" resultId="IDupCodeViolation" ver="2" />
    </VersionInfos>

    <ExecutedTestsDetails>
        <Total authChange="0;" authFail="3;" change="0" changePass="0" changeTotal="0" fail="3" name="Passed / Total" pass="13" time="0:00:00.120" total="16">
            <Project authChange="0;" authFail="3;" change="0" changePass="0" changeTotal="0" fail="3" name="test" pass="13" time="0:00:00.120" total="16">
                <TestSuite authChange="0;" authFail="3;" change="0" changePass="0" changeTotal="0" fail="3" id="wk:///test/Premera.tst" name="Premera.tst" pass="13" time="0:00:00.120" total="16">
                    <TestSuite auth="kchen" authChange="0;" authFail="3;" change="0" changePass="0" changeTotal="0" fail="3" id="wk:///test/Premera.tst#0000000000" name="Test Suite: Test Suite" pass="13" root="true" time="0:00:00.120" total="16">
                        <TestSuite auth="kchen" authChange="0;" authFail="1;" change="0" changePass="0" changeTotal="0" fail="1" id="wk:///test/Premera.tst#0000000000#0000000002" name="Test Suite: Test Suite A" pass="2" time="0:00:00.026" total="3">
                            <Test auth="kchen" authChange="0;" authFail="1;" change="0" changePass="0" changeTotal="0" fail="1" id="wk:///test/Premera.tst#0000000000#0000000002#0000000006" name="Test 1: Test A" pass="0" startTime="1471558622262" time="0:00:00.015" tool="Test A" total="1">
                                <assoc id="308" tag="pr" />
                                <assoc id="303" tag="req" />
                            </Test>
                            <Test auth="kchen" authChange="0;" authFail="0;" change="0" changePass="0" changeTotal="0" fail="0" id="wk:///test/Premera.tst#0000000000#0000000002#0000000007" name="Test 2: Test B" pass="1" startTime="1471558622279" time="0:00:00.005" tool="Test B" total="1">
                                <assoc id="309" tag="pr" />
                                <assoc id="303" tag="req" />
                            </Test>
                            <Test auth="kchen" authChange="0;" authFail="0;" change="0" changePass="0" changeTotal="0" fail="0" id="wk:///test/Premera.tst#0000000000#0000000002#0000000008" name="Test 3: Test C" pass="1" startTime="1471558622287" time="0:00:00.006" tool="Test C" total="1">
                                <assoc id="310" tag="pr" />
                                <assoc id="303" tag="req" />
                            </Test>
                        </TestSuite>
...
    </ExecutedTestsDetails>
</ResultsSession>
```

**But the result Webservice SOAP created by SOAtest is like that:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Report time="Tue Mar 27 14:42:40 EDT 2018" app="SOAtest" version="9.9.5.20160601" project="C:\Users\rejean.therrien\parasoft\workspace\Test\DneOnline\Calculator.tst">
    <TestSuite name="Test Suite: Test Suite" runConcurrently="false" testPath="/Test Suite: Test Suite">
        <Requirements>
            <Notes>Created from: http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?WSDL&#xD;&#10;Timestamp: 2018-01-18 13:00:44</Notes>
        </Requirements>
        <DataSources>
            <DataSource name="Table: New Datasource" type="Table">
                <Row index="0">
                    <Column name="intA">10</Column>
                    <Column name="intB">5</Column>
                    <Column name="intResultAdd">15</Column>
                    <Column name="intResultDivide">2</Column>
                </Row>
...         
            </DataSource>
        </DataSources>
        <TestFlowLogic/>
        <TestSuite name="Test Suite: CalculatorSoap" runConcurrently="false" testPath="/Test Suite: Test Suite/Test Suite: CalculatorSoap">
            <TestFlowLogic/>
            <Test name="Test 1: Add" testPath="/Test Suite: Test Suite/Test Suite: CalculatorSoap">
                <Requirements>
                    <GRSIDs>
                        <ID>303</ID>
                        <ID>308</ID>
                    </GRSIDs>
                </Requirements>
                <Configuration type="SOAP Client" wsdlURI="http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?WSDL" soapVersion="SOAP 1.1" timeout="30000" outgoingEncoding="UTF-8" dataSource="Table: New Datasource" styleUse="document/literal" attachmentEncapsulation="MIME" operation="Add">
                    <Transport type="HTTP 1.0">
                        <Configuration endpoint="http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx" chunking="false" followRedirects="true" connection="Close Connection"/>
                    </Transport>
                    <Input><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>&#10;<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">&#10; <SOAP-ENV:Body>&#10;  <Add xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">&#10;   <intA>${intA}</intA>&#10;   <intB>${intB}</intB>&#10;  </Add>&#10; </SOAP-ENV:Body>&#10;</SOAP-ENV:Envelope></Input>
                    <Requirements>
                        <Notes>Test client for operation "Add" in "${WSDL}".</Notes>
                    </Requirements>
                    <ChainedTools/>
                </Configuration>
            </Test>
...
            </TestSuite>
    </TestSuite>
</Report>
```

Completely different :(

Comment: Please provide some code to show us what you get, what you try and what error / problme you get

Answer (score 0):

Rejean,

The first report is produced by SOAtest v9.9.3 however I see the same syntax with v9.10.4.
How did you get your SOAtest report?
You said "Webservice SOAP" but do you use SOAtest' SOAP interface to get report?
Or maybe are you using SOAtest cli interface: soatestcli[.exe]?
If yes, what parameters are you using to get report during test (tst file) execution?
Usually, when using cli you should run such command:

```
soatestcli -data <workspace_location> -resource <project name> -config "team://Team Configuration" -report <Report_location> -localsettings acme_policy.settings
```

where Report_location defines where you should find xml and html report.
You can however use XML Transformation which allows you to change format of report.
Then you have to check content of -localsettings parameter (usually file, here acme_policy.settings) where you can find additional information about report creation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not able to execute SOAtest in command line. Suppose, my license :(. And it's probably the main reason.

Comment: So how did you get your report?

Comment: I use the GUI SOAtest contextual menu from .tst file: Right Click, Structure Report, Default Structure Report, Save As XML...

Comment: I tried this too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36551248/how-to-generate-a-report-using-soatest

Comment: Structure Report contains different set of data.You have to ask for command line feature which allows you get the correct one.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will ask to get command line feature and I'll let you know my results. ;)

Comment: FYI. Finally, after to get the 'Command line' license, I'v got the good XML results as indicate by SOATestToMTM open source. Thanks for help.